# Стилизация atom под sublime

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, atom

Какой код прописать в в файле стилей текстового редактора atom, чтобы цвет шрифта и синтаксиса, а также подсвечивание синтаксиса и цвет фона были как в sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Sublime Вас какая именно тема интересует - Monokai?

Попробуйте [так](https://atom.io/themes/monokai). Или [так](https://atom.io/themes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=monokai).

Comment: Которая стоит по умолчанию. Белый текст, красные переменные и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...